# Pandas find rows with value in any column

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading data from a lot of csv files as pandas dataframes. But the format of csv files is not consistent. An example:

```
Unnamed:1 Unnamed:2 .... Unnamed:20
Data      NaN       .... NaN
Nan       Temp       .... NaN
id        name      .... year
.
.
```

Now I want to find the first row which contains `id` or `ID` or `Id`, make that row as column names and drop any rows above it. So finally I will get:

```
id        name      .... year
.
.
```

Now `id` column may not always be the first column, i.e, `Unnamed:1` column, so I am checking entire rows like so:

```
df.isin(["id"]).any(axis=1)
```

The issue with the above code is that I am not sure how to check for all different ways `id` may be written, i.e, `ID/Id/id`. Ideally, I would like to use regex here, but I know it can be done without regex for a particular column like so:

```
df['Unnamed:1'].str.lower().str.contains('id')
```

I am just not getting how to do both at the same time, i.e., check for all ways `id` may be written in all the columns.

Comment: This helped me: https://www.statology.org/pandas-find-value-any-column/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for match first `ID/id/Id` substring in all columns by filter output rows before and then convert first row to columns:

```
mask = (df.select_dtypes(object)
          .apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('id', case=False))
          .any(axis=1)
          .cumsum()
          .gt(0))

df = df[mask].copy()
df.columns = df.iloc[0].rename(None)
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Another idea for test not subtrings:

```
mask = df.isin(['id','ID','Id']).any(axis=1).cumsum().gt(0)

df = df[mask].copy()
df.columns = df.iloc[0].rename()
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: @Ank - Added `select_dtypes` for get only strings columns.